# Can you play Mount and Blade multiplayer with mods?

Tags: mods, mount-and-blade-warband

I am planning on playing Mount and Blade Warband multiplayer with a friend later this week but then i realized i have the mod Diplomacy installed so i wanted to know if we could play with mods installed if he installed it too.

Answer (score 1):

Not all mods in Mount and Blade Warband support multiple player. You can check it from The [Caravanserai - Released Warband Mods](http://forums.taleworlds.com/index.php?board=165.0), where [S] indicate the mod Diplomacy only supports single player.